# ASP.NET Remove Item from siteMap does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, sitemap

I discovered a kind of strange behavior in my applicataion.

I have a menu, which is populated by a siteMap.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDataSource" runat="server" SiteMapProvider="examGenSiteMap" />

<asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="siteMapDataSource" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" OnMenuItemDataBound="MenuExamGen_MenuItemDataBound">
    // Some Item styles
</asp:Menu>
```

Now I have added a OnMenuItemDataBound in which I check, if the roles in the siteMap matches with the user role. If not: remove that item, so the user can't see it.

```
        if (!((SiteMapNode)e.Item.DataItem).Roles.Contains(Session["Role"].ToString()))
        {
            mainMenu.Items.Remove(e.Item);
        }
```

I debugged this code multiple times, it works fine. All the items I want to remove are identified by the if and the Remove() function gets those items as argument.

The only problem: On my webpage all items ar still shown, and I have no idea why.

Comment: what is that mainMenu variable?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540822/asp-net-how-to-hide-a-menu-item-from-visitor

Comment: the mainMenu variale is the name of my Menu :P

Comment: I've seen this post too, and tried to change it as suggested. Still the same error: All nodes are displayed.

Comment: can you pls share the full code of OnMenuItemDataBound

Comment: See the answer (because of length of a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have solved the problem.
I don't know, why

```
mainMenu.Items.Remove(e.Item);
```

is not working anymore. You need to remove child elements of the root element.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu mainMenu = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)sender;

if (!((SiteMapNode)e.Item.DataItem).Roles.Contains(Session["Role"].ToString()))
{
    mainMenu.Items[0].ChildItems.Remove(e.Item);
}
```

But thanks for trying to help me :)